# CSS Drop Down Border Only On 'ul li ul li:hover a'

Tags: html, css

Please see below,

The border should only appear on hovered `<a>` tags, however it appears on all `<a>` tags within the nested

**HTML**

```
<ul><li>Home</li>
  <li><a href='#'>About</a></li>
  <li>
    <a href='#'>Portfolio</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href='#'>Web Design</a></li>
      <li><a>Web Development</a></li>
      <li><a>Illustrations</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Blog</li>
  <li>Contact</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 20px 50px 150px;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #E3CAA1;
}

ul {
  text-align: left;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px 4px 17px 0;
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
ul li {
  font: bold 12px/18px sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  background: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
ul li:hover {
  background: #555;
  color: #fff;
}

ul li:hover a {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
ul li ul {
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 48px;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -transition: opacity 0.2s;
}
ul li ul li { 
  background: #555; 
  display: block; 
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
}
ul li ul li:hover { background: #666; }
ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ul li:hover > a {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

">" means that we make the relationship only with the immediate child, and not the nested ones.

Comment: thanks mate. can you explain why this works as opposed to the other way around?

Answer (score 0):

Change hover link to the below.

```
ul li li:hover a {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have borders only around the hovered , then replace the code

```
ul li:hover a {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

**with**

```
ul li a:hover {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```